# Accepted timezone strings for DateTime library in ruby > Ruby 2.4.1

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone, rubygems, fluentd

I am trying to convert the timestamps to UTC from various timezones in Ruby. The below snippet works.

`DateTime.strptime(["2022-02-02 10:46:34", "EST"].join(' '), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z').new_offset(0)`

I wanted to know the accepted timezone mappings/strings. But, Ruby docs don't seem to be having any information about this.

Thanks

Comment: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING`, https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html.

Comment: @razvans I have checked this. But this is for a different library and most of the timezones are not supported with DateTime libray.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones